# Multiple images on slide show

Tags: show, slide

I'm trying to make a slide show (html/css/javasacript/whatever works) to obtain something like that :

[slide show i'd like to code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmMbX.png)

With two arrows on the right/left to display more images (maximum images displayed at once would be 4).

I saw some tutorials on w3school but unfortunately it's not exactly what i wish.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is not really a question. What do you want?

Comment: I actually found this which looks pretty good : http://materializecss.com/carousel.html  however how can i integrate it to my page ? do i need to create js files ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this on https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp
I changed it so that it can display multiple images.

```js
<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
   <img src="player.jpg" style="width:25%">
 <img src="Untitled.jpg" style="width:25%">
 <img src="Lighthouse.jpg" style="width:25%">
 <img src="Untitled.jpg" style="width:25%">
  <div class="text">1, 2, 3, & 4</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
     <img src="Untitled.jpg" style="width:25%">
 <img src="Untitled.jpg" style="width:25%">
 <img src="Lighthouse.jpg" style="width:25%">
 <img src="player.jpg" style="width:25%">
  <div class="text">5, 6, 7, & 8</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
     <img src="Untitled.jpg" style="width:25%">
 <img src="Untitled.jpg" style="width:25%">
 <img src="Lighthouse.jpg" style="width:25%">
 <img src="player.jpg" style="width:25%">
  <div class="text">5, 6, 7, & 8</div>
</div>
```